# Is this question on topic?

Tags: discussion

I think it belongs on superuser or stackoverflow.
[LilyPond - how to write a basic makefile](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/92636/34153)

Answer (score 6):

Good question. Makefiles per se would be off topic. I think in this case it's clearly relevant to writing scores using LilyPond or command line tools for ABC like abc2ps or abcm2ps. But it *is* a stretch and we shouldn't open the door to all technology related to these tools.

"What OS to choose for LilyPond?", "Which shell for running LilyPond?" -- these would clearly be over the line.